# How to convert uint16_t to int in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

[image]How do i make hexValue convert to int data type？

Comment: Are you familiar with a cast in Objective-C?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried just assigning the value or variable to an int? What happened? What error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

try this,

uint16_t var = 65535;

int variable = var;